# JWT Authentication with Django REST Framework

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-jwt

I am having some trouble authenticating requests to a Django REST endpoint. I have a token-auth URL which points towards rest_framework_jwt.views.obtain_jwt_token, e.g.:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('token-auth/', obtain_jwt_token),
    path('verify-token/', verify_jwt_token),
    path('current_user/', CurrentUserView.as_view()),
]
```

where CurrentUserView is:

```
class CurrentUserView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        print(request.user)
        serializer = UserSerializer(request.user)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

if I create a token in the browser by visiting http://localhost/token-auth/, I can then verify it using the command:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"token":<MY_TOKEN>}' http://localhost/verify-token/
```

however the same request called to the http://localhost/current_user/ returns a 400 code:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"token":<MY_TOKEN>}' http://localhost/current_user/

{"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}
```

Framework settings are:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
    ),
}
```

And Django is being run in a container with the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
EXPOSE 8000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide jwt token in your requests. here is the sample:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: jwt <MY_TOKEN>" http://localhost/current_user/
```

You are sending token by mistake in data section, instead you should provide it in Authorization header.

Comment: Thanks @Reza. You were correct, the verify_jwt_token view requires the token to be sent as data, as I guess it is not an authentication method, but rather just a form response

Comment: any time my friend :)